# ¿De dónde viene la palabra "chiclé"?

Tags: etimología

[**Chiclé**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8jeiRyI) es

> 1. m. Tecnol. En algunos motores de explosión, dispositivo que regula el paso del combustible al carburador.

pero sin ninguna indicación de su procedencia. ¿Se sabe algo de su origen?

Answer (score 4):

De acuerdo a la web [Etimologías de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?chicle.-) la palabra *chiclé* (o chicler) parece ser una corrupción del francés "chicleur" (vaporizador).

Esta web, construye cada entrada en base a colaboraciones de diferentes usuarios, y hay quien apunta (o corrige) en esa misma entrada que el término correcto es "[gicleur](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/gicleur)"  y no *chicleur* (en diccionarios de francés, como por ejemplo wordreference, aparece *gicleur* pero no *chicleur*, que confirma lo aportado por el segundo usuario en esa entrada de Etimologías de Chile).

Answer (score 3):

Consultando la palabra en el fichero general de la RAE, [la segunda ficha](http://web.frl.es/FICHERO/FICHERO/LETRA_C/LETRA_C_I_PDF/CHICL%C3%89/00000127.pdf) (PDF) nos da la respuesta:

> *¿Por qué llamamos estúpidamente «chiclé» a esa piececilla de nuestro coche a la que los franceses llaman «gicleur» —de ahí nuestra torpe imitación fonética— y que sirve para inyectar la gasolina en el carburador?*
>
> ABC Madrid, 30/12/1971 (España).

Así pues, el primer paso está dado, pero no nos quedemos ahí. Si buscamos en diccionarios etimológicos franceses obtenemos datos interesantes. El CNRTL [nos dice](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/gicler) que *gicler* (de la que deriva *gicleur* y que significa "brotar") proviene del francés provenzal *jicler, gigler* y que está emparentada con otras palabras como *cisclar*, *cisler* y *gisclar*, teniendo todas un étimo común en *cisculare*, que es de origen incierto aunque se estima que proviene de una corrupción de *fistulare* ("tocar la flauta") influenciada por *sibilare* ("silbar"). Nótese la idea de "inyectar" (aire en la flauta) o de "brotar" (aire de los labios) en todos los términos.

---

Nota: *fistulare* en realidad es *tocar la fístula*:

> **[fístula](http://dle.rae.es/?id=I0ugTNb)**
>
> 1. f. Cañón o arcaduz por donde pasa el agua u otro líquido.
> 2. f. Instrumento musical de viento, parecido a una flauta.

Nos encontramos pues con un concepto que ya contiene la palabra *chiclé*: el de un objeto tubular ("cañón") por el que pasa un líquido (agua, aire o gasolina).